# MongoDB : limit query to a field and array projection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that contains following information

```
{
  "_id" : 1, 
  "info" : { "createdby" : "xyz" }, 
  "states" : [ 11, 10, 9, 3, 2, 1 ]}
}
```

I project only states by using query

```
db.jobs.find({},{states:1})
```

Then I get only states (and whole array of state values) ! or I can select only one state in that array by

```
db.jobs.find({},{states : {$slice : 1} })
```

And then I get only one state value, but along with all other fields in the document as well.

Is there a way to select only "states" field, and at the same time slice only one element of the array. Of course, I can exclude fields but I would like to have a solution in which I can specify both conditions.

Comment: [`aggregation`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/) is your friend. `$unwind` states; use `$match` to filter and `$project` to reshape or exclude fields

Comment: can you post your expected output ?

Comment: @yogesh The expected output should contain only "states" with only one array value.

Comment: So for simple field selection, the field selection works alright. Will it be a good idea to allow these simple limiting expressions inside find projections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1> Using [mongo projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) like

`<field>: <1 or true>   Specify the inclusion of a field`

and

`<field>: <0 or false>  Specify the suppression of the field`

so your query as

```
db.jobs.find({},{states : {$slice : 1} ,"info":0,"_id":0})
```

2> Other way using [mongo aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/applications/aggregation/) as

```
db.jobs.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$states"
  }, {
    "$match": {
      "states": 11
    }
  }, // match states (optional)
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "states": {
        "$first": "$states"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "states": 1
    }
  })
```

Comment: I used aggreation to include  [ { $project : "states" }, { $unwind : "states" }, { $limit : 1} ]